# Area under curve and its volume as solid of revolution

Tags: mathematics, f#, numerical-methods

I would like to know if there is some more "elegant" way to write these 3 functions. Any tip or idea is welcome.

```
open System

module Calculus =
    let area f a b =
        let dx = 0.001
        seq { for x in a .. dx .. b -> (f x) * dx }
        |> Seq.sum

    let rotate f x =
        let y = f x
        y * y * Math.PI

    let volume f =
        area (rotate f)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let f x = x * 2.0

    printfn "Running..."

    printfn "%f" (Calculus.area f 1.0 10.0)
    printfn "%f" (Calculus.volume f 1.0 10.0)

    0
```

---

**Note**

I understand the method for integration I am using here is not the best around, but it is not the point here. Let's focus on its implementation.

Comment: Looks good to me. Not much to review! One small possible improvement: `f |> rotate |> area`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would rewrite this:

First, pipe *everything* that you can. It's easier to follow the linear transition of `a |> b |> c` rather than `c (b a)`.

Second, compose where possible. Compositions are *powerful*, and can allow you to abstract things away much more effectively.

Third, order function parameters by most -> least generic. We see `f a b`, but F# sees `let f = f a; f b`, so make sure your parameters are ordered by *least-significant* first.

```
module Calculus =
    let area f a b =
        let dx = 0.001
        { a .. dx .. b }
        |> Seq.sumBy (f >> (*) dx)

    let rotate f x =
        let multX = x |> f |> (*)
        Math.PI |> multX |> multX

    let volume = rotate >> area

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let shape = (2.0 |> (*), 1.0, 10.0)
    printfn "%f" (shape |||> Calculus.area)
    printfn "%f" (shape |||> Calculus.volume)
```

This ends up being three lines longer, but it's *clearer*. It's completely obvious what is happening, and the piping makes it easier to follow. We replaced the custom sequence generator with a basic one, and used `sumBy` to make our intent clearer. We want to sum `f(x) * dx`.

This also ends up one line shorter, and that's only because we rewrote `volume` as a pure composition, and pushed it to a one-line definition. I recommend doing this for things that are 2-3 steps. (So even `let volume f = f |> rotate |> area` would be acceptable.)

Instead of building the `f` in the main, we build the `shape` itself, and then pipe all three arguments of that shape to our `area` and `volume` methods. (Since the arguments are the same for each call.)

This means our `shape` is reusable, and we could build a function:

```
let printShape s =
    printfn "%f" (s |||> area)
    printfn "%f" (s |||> volume)

let shapes =
    let f = 2.0 |> (*)
    [(f, 1.0, 10.0); (f, 2.0, 10.0)]
shapes |> List.iter printShape
```

Now we can build more test-cases pretty easily and functionally. Because `printShapes` takes a single parameter of a `(float -> float) * float * float`, we can pass the entire shape to it and then pass each portion of the tuple as individual parameters.

Comment: I really like your version of `volume`, but I find your version of `rotate` overly complicated. Anyway, thank you for showing me some different ways to think functionally.